# JAVA JPA Containing Hibernate long search is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am trying to do a search based on name mobile number and id
Here : id is in string
name is in string

if queried with both works fine but for the same when i search with mobile number(Long) throws an error

`"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [%9%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)];`

my code as follows

controller

```
@GetMapping("searching")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> searching(@RequestParam("Id") final String Id,
             @RequestParam("name") final String name,
            
            @RequestParam("phoneNumber") final Long phoneNumber,
             HttpSession session) {
        response = new Response();
        try {

            List<UserDTO> data = userService.searching(Id,  name,  phoneNumber );
            if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                response.setMessage(StringConstance.SUCCESSFUL);
                response.setData(data);
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body(response);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response);
    }
```

Service

```
public List<UserDTO> searching(String Id, String name,
            Long phoneNumber) {
     
        List<UserDTO> userDto = userRepository
                .findByIdAndNameContainingIgnoreCaseAndPhoneNumberContaining(
                        Id,  name,   phoneNumber)
                .stream().map(user -> mapToDTO(user, new UserDTO())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return userDto;
    }
```

Repository

```
List<User> findByIdAndNameContainingIgnoreCaseAndPhoneNumberContaining(
                        Id,  name,   phoneNumber)
```